# Having trouble representing and understanding sets

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

Specifically, the concept of set referred to here: http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-16.html#%_sec_2.3.3

I understand how the data structures work and how to traverse through them, but the use of it is tougher to conceptualize.

Would someone mind explaining it in different words, perhaps that might help it click. Thanks so much.

Comment: What does "the use of it" mean? If you understand the representation and how to manipulate it, what part is confusing?

Comment: [I know it might be ignorant, I'm trying to understand it though]"One way to represent a set is as a list of its elements in which no element appears more than once." - why must no element appear more than once? This would be my first question.

Comment: "why must no element appear more than once" Because that's the definition of a set. A set is a collection of distinct objects. The concept comes from math. Svante provides a good example of when this would be useful. (don't worry about ignorance because we're all just here to help)

Comment: An abstract data type is really about the behavior of operations.  A set provides a few operations, including intersection, set membership, and subtraction.  A particular representation will make certain operations easier to implement than others.  A representation that says "The items must be are unique!" can make it easier to implement intersection, as opposed to a representation that allows duplicates.  So when you see restrictive statements with regards to representation issues, consider if it affects how easy or not it makes it to implement the abstract operations correctly.

Comment: @dyoo thank you, that really helps me understand, i saw similar wording in SICP a little further along too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a set `(a b c)`, then trying to insert `a` into it will result in the same set `(a b c)`.  It is just a collection that has the constraint/guarantee that no value will be duplicate.

Example use:  You want to find all words used in a text, but their frequencies are irrelevant.  If you have a *set*, then the algorithm is just: go through all words and add each into the set.  Since the set automatically throws away all duplicates, it is the correct result when you finish.

Comment: to ask another question, if you don't mind: "Union-set computes the union of two sets, which is the set containing each element that appears in either argument" and "Intersection-set computes the intersection of two sets, which is the set containing only elements that appear in both arguments." - would you have examples to help understand those statements?

Comment: Sets are a fundamental concept of mathematics. Wikipedia seems to have a good explanation of basic operations with examples http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29#Basic_operations

Comment: zallarak: take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory); it sounds like you're unfamiliar with a particular math concept.  Take a look at those articles first, and see if that helps.